# How to change tcp keepalive timer using python script?

Tags: python, tcp, keep-alive

In my python script, I have activate TCP Keepalive using this command:

```
x = s.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
```

My goal is for socket connection to get closed, if there is no transmission(*) for 5 minutes. I am working on Windows and my python script is only receiving and not transmitting any data to client program.

What I know is, by default, if no transmission will be there for 2 hours, then only I can close the connection using try and except. I know, for windows, I can manually reduce this waiting time by going to registry. But is there is a way by which, I can modify it from my script?

(*) here "no transmission" means "something quietly eats packets on the network" rather than "I'm not trying to send anything."

Comment: clarified what "no transmission" means.

Comment: Why not just set a read timeout?

Answer (score 73):

You can set the TCP keepalive timers on an already-open socket using setsockopt().

```
import socket

def set_keepalive_linux(sock, after_idle_sec=1, interval_sec=3, max_fails=5):
    """Set TCP keepalive on an open socket.

    It activates after 1 second (after_idle_sec) of idleness,
    then sends a keepalive ping once every 3 seconds (interval_sec),
    and closes the connection after 5 failed ping (max_fails), or 15 seconds
    """
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, after_idle_sec)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, interval_sec)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, max_fails)

def set_keepalive_osx(sock, after_idle_sec=1, interval_sec=3, max_fails=5):
    """Set TCP keepalive on an open socket.

    sends a keepalive ping once every 3 seconds (interval_sec)
    """
    # scraped from /usr/include, not exported by python's socket module
    TCP_KEEPALIVE = 0x10
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPALIVE, interval_sec)
```

For equivalent options on windows [refer to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Looking through the [Python source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dfe327390cc2/Modules/socketmodule.c#l3783), it seems you need to set `SO_KEEPALIVE` with `sock.setsockopt` similar to in Unix, and [optionally?] set `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` with `sock.ioctl`.

Comment: Note that the TCP_* constants used here are specific to Linux. For instance they are not available on OS/X

Comment: osx `man tcp` contains an option `TCP_KEEPALIVE` that accepts seconds between probes, that is equivalent to `TCP_KEEPINTVL` in linux. option is not exported in Python 2.7 or 3.3, but I think it's possible to use the correct integer value `0x10` as key.

Comment: @DimaTisnek TCP_KEEPINTVL looks equivalent, but how did you get that value `0x10`?

Comment: Darwin `tcp.h`: https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/netinet/tcp.h

Comment: Any ideas for Solaris - '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_TCP', no SOL_SOCKET either

Answer (score 16):

For windows, in python:

This will enable socket keep alive, with a 10 second keep alive time and a 3 second keep alive interval.

```
sock.ioctl(socket.SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, (1, 10000, 3000))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have combined the above answers and made a single-function version for Linux, Darwin, and Windows.

https://pypi.org/project/keepalive-socket/

```
pip install keepalive-socket
```

```py
import socket, keepalive

# keepalive.set(socket, after_idle_sec=60, interval_sec=60, max_fails=5)

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
keepalive.set(client_socket)
```