# asyncore close old sockets

Tags: python, tcp, asyncore

I have got tcp server on python with asyncore:

```
class AsyncClientHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self,sock):
        asyncore.dispatcher_with_send.__init__(self,sock)

        self.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
        self.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)

        self.message=""
        self.protocol=Protocol(DBSession, logger)

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.message+=data
            while TERMINATOR in self.message:   
                index=self.message.index(TERMINATOR)
                msg=self.message[:index]
                self.message=self.message[index+len(TERMINATOR):]

                answer=self.protocol.process_msg(msg, DBSession, tarif_dict)
                if answer:
                    msg = HEADER+answer+TERMINATOR
                    self.send(msg)

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

class AsyncServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port): 
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)

        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
        self.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)

        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is None:
            pass
        else:
            sock, addr = pair
            logging.info("Incoming connection from %s",repr(addr))
            AsyncClientHandler(sock)
```

Some clients do not close the connection, so at some point the server crashes due to the large number of sockets.

How can I close an inactive socket after some time? settimeout not work.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could use TCP's Keepalive (like you already did) and set its delay, pings... But this apporach should only be used for long-lasting connections and is only available on Unixes. Have some read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248132/how-to-change-tcp-keepalive-timer-using-python-script/).

You can also make some scheduling of sockets, closing them when some time passes or delay them when they're active. I made an example working with your code:

```
import sched, time

class SocketSched(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.to_run = []
        self.scheds = {}
        self.start()

    def add(self, what):
        self.to_run.append(what.values()[0])
        self.scheds.update(what)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.to_run:
                run = self.to_run.pop()
                if not run.empty(): run.run()
                else: self.to_run.append(run)
```

Here we define new class of scheduler in different thread - this is important, `sched` module would continuously block, like `asyncore.loop()`.
This needs modificating your code a bit:

```
class AsyncClientHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self,sock, sch_class):
        ...
        self.delay = 10
        self.sch_class = sch_class
        self.sch = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        self.sch_class.add({self.fileno(): self.sch})
        self.event = self.sch_class.scheds[self.fileno()].enter(self.delay, 1, self.handle_close, ())

    ...

    def delay_close(self):
        self.sch_class.scheds[self.fileno()].cancel(self.event)
        self.event = self.sch_class.scheds[self.fileno()].enter(self.delay, 1, self.handle_close, ())

    ...

    def handle_close(self):
        try:
            self.sch_class.scheds[self.fileno()].cancel(self.event)
        except:
            pass
        ...
```

`self.delay` is a timeout in seconds. After this time passes, and no action delays it, socket will be closed. Line in handle_close() ensures it won't be called twice due to task in scheduler.

Now you have to add `self.delay_close()` to the beginning of every method that ensures socket is active, eg. `handle_read()`.

Server class (gets instance of SocketSched and passes it to new channels):

```
class AsyncServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port, sch_class): 
        ...
        self.sch_class = sch_class

    ...

    def handle_accept(self):
    ...
            AsyncClientHandler(sock, self.sch_class)
```

Ready. Using this:

```
server = AsyncServer('', 1337, SocketSched())
asyncore.loop()
```

This solution works, but can be error-prone on some close events. Anyway, sockets will read, delay, and close when given timeout occurs. Unfortunately running such scheduling loop uses some CPU.