# Python sockets auto close

Tags: python, sockets

I have a client (on `windows`) that runs in the background; the client connects to the server (on `linux`) and waits for instructions.

The problem is that the client can receive data at a 10 minutes time frame. After that the data isn't received at the client side.

In the server side it look like the client still connected but the message don't reach it.

I don't know why, but I can't find the cause. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779973/how-to-set-keep-alive-timer-in-python-2-5-running-in-windows-7

Comment: I'll try it.. Thanks