# How can you detect when a TCP client disconnects with Python's select()?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a simple server that uses select(), that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import select, socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)
server.bind(('localhost', 50000))
server.listen(5)

# TCP Keepalive Options
#server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
#server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
#server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 3)
#server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)

inputs = [server]

print "Listening on port 50000"

while True:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, [], inputs)

    for s in readable:
        if s is server:
            connection, client_address = s.accept()
            print "New client connected: %s" % (client_address,)

            connection.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(connection)
        else:
            data = s.recv(1024)

            if data:
                print "Data from %s: %s" % (s.getpeername(), data.replace('\n', ''))
            else:
                print "%s disconnected" % (s.getpeername(),)

                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()

    for s in exceptional:
        print "Client at %s dropped out" % (s.getpeername(),)
        inputs.remove(s)
        s.close()
```

I can connect to it using telnet clients, and it works great. It doesn't respond to the clients, but for this simple example, that's fine.

The problem I'm seeing is this: if a client disconnects without sending a TCP FIN or TCP RST, the server doesn't seem to ever figure out that the client is gone.

I simulate the client disappearing by doing this:

- Run the server
- Connect a telnet client to the server
- Use iptables to block the telnet client from talking to the server

As far as I know, the normal solution to this is to turn on TCP Keepalive, which I do by uncommenting the TCP Keepalive section.
When I do that, and follow the same test procedure to make a client disappear in the middle of a connected session, it seems that when the socket
times out, select() stops blocking, and returns the client in the "readable" list (as opposed to the exceptional list). This
causes my server to try to read data from that socket with s.recv(1024), which crashes the server (s.recv() throws a socket.error exception).

I know I can probably catch the exception and deal with it, but I'm more curious why:

1. select() doesn't pick up on the fact that the client disappeared

   - I would think one of the most important types of exceptions that select() would be looking for is if the client disappeared. Or is it looking for garbled input?
2. Even when I explicitly enable TCP Keepalive, select() still puts the timed out socket into the readable list instead of the exceptional list

Is this expected? Is there a way to have select() put clients that disappeared into the exceptional list instead? Or is it important not to assume that just because select() said a socket is ready for reading, recv() won't fail?

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of the question I asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53471205/6423456), as this one deals specifically with select(), and how it handles exceptions. This one actually includes code which I learned from the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is detecting a TCP socket disconnect in Python possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471205/is-detecting-a-tcp-socket-disconnect-in-python-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the keepalive, and it detects the failure, the `select()` should report the socket as both readable and writable. Then when you try to perform one of those operations you should get an error. Use `try/except` around the `s.recv()` call to detect `socket.error`.

You might naively assume that this would be reported as an "exceptional situation", but it isn't. That's used for normal exceptions on a valid socket, such as out-of-band data.

Comment: My code contains the exact thing you recommend, which I borrowed from the exact link you posted - enabling and setting the TCP Keepalive timers. I'm just wondering what select() is looking for in terms of exceptions if not for clients that disappeared, and why when I set the TCP keepalive timers, select() still can't tell that there's a problem, and instead, thinks the client is ready to send data.

Comment: Sorrry, didn't notice them because they were commented out.