# How can you tell when a server dies from the client

Tags: python, sockets

How can you tell a server has closed from the client side? I close my server before i close my client which has a loop in it that is now infinite because it is not recieving any input. So how can i tell the server has been closed from the perspective of the client. I am doing this all in python.

Comment: "It depends". UDP? No way to tell without implementing your own application-layer logic. TCP? Depends on settings, including connection flags. See [How to change TCP keepalive timer using Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248132/how-to-change-tcp-keepalive-timer-using-python-script). If that doesn't answer your question, [edit] to add a [mre] so others can see exactly _how_ you're creating the socket -- if you're using a network framework other than the standard-library `socket` module, a different answer may be called for.

Comment: You might also do a general review of the search results for `site:stackoverflow.com python TCP keepalive`; there's quite a lot there.

Comment: (in _some_ cases you'll already get a RST from the server, causing the client to find out the connection is dead immediately; it's only the case where that doesn't get through that you need any of this in the first place).

Comment: I'm not sure this about detecting an abnormally disconnected server rather than a normally disconnected server that sends a FIN that makes it to the client. We'd need to see the client code, so I'd close the question because it lacks the necessary detail.