# cherrypy check connection status

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy api that is intended to run for a long time on the server.

I have an unreliable client that can die or close connection for various reasons that are out of my control.

During the time my server api runs, I want to periodically check the status of the connection, making sure the client is still listening and abort my operation if the client has gone away.

I could not find any good place describing how to poll the connection status while serving a cherrypy request.

One example of such a long run is computing md5 of multiple big files (of tens of GBs) in chunks of small buffer (limited memory).

I don't need any solutions that shorten the runtime since that is not my goal here. I want to keep this connection open for as long as I can, but abort if it is closed.

Here is the simple sample of my code:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def foo(self):
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    def run():
        for result in get_results(): # get_results() is a heavy method mentioned
            yield json.dumps(result)
    return run()
foo._cp_config = {'response.stream': True}
```

Comment: How about a WebSockets connection? https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python It seems to have CherryPy integration as well (?)

Comment: ws4py uses a heartbeat as defined by RFC6455, I'm not sure this could apply easily here.

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way to know that the client has died is to try to write some data to the socket, which for CherryPy can be done with `yield`. You must yield non-empty strings, so you'd have to be returning a Content-Type that can handle some filler text, like some extra spaces after the opening `<head>` tag of an HTML document. If the client closes the connection, the CherryPy server will stop requesting additional yielded data from the handler (and call any `close` method on the generator so you can clean up).

Comment: I have updated my question with the sample code. I am not sure where I need to have the close method so that I can cleanup.

Comment: just finished reading about yield functions. fumanchu@ was right and cherrypy does call close on generator when the connection is closed, that's all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CherryPy doesn't provide you with any mechanism to detect that a client died. It will only tell you if a response took too long to complete (and therefore be sent out).

You may refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686490/detect-socket-hangup-without-sending-or-receiving/5686720) for more information.